# Issues with Mvc.LocalizationSample.Web for ASP.NET core

Tags: asp.net, github, asp.net-core

I'm using the [sample code](https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/dev/samples/Localization.StarterWeb) associated with asp.net core to see how to localise a site under .NET core, however the readme is empty and the project json refers to packages that don't exist on nuget.org

```
  "dependencies": {
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.Localization": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools": {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "type": "build"
},
"Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.UserSecrets": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0-*",
"Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0-*"
```

},

acording to [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc/) Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc is currently at 1.0.1

I've posted to the issues on GitHub but I wondered if there's something obvious I'm missing and if not maybe it will help someone else looking for similar guidance.

Comment: the entropy repo is something for experimental stuff. looks to me like they have updated it to use asp.net core 1.1 which has not yet been released. the asp.net team is most likely using that to test the latest code. I would focus more on the docs for localization https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/localization.html

Comment: or just change the versions to be 1.0.* in your own copy

Answer (score 0):

the entropy repo is something for experimental stuff. looks to me like they have updated it to use asp.net core 1.1 which has not yet been released. the asp.net team is most likely using that to test the latest code.

to get that working with the current release you could change all those 1.1.0 versions to 1.0.*

Answer (score 0):

On GitHub you get that pulldown in the top-left corner. Clock on it, select tags and choose "1.0.0" to get the repository tagged with the 1.0.0 version and the dependencies for 1.0.0.

It gives you the following url: https://github.com/aspnet/Entropy/tree/1.0.0/samples/Localization.StarterWeb

Using the dev branch with 1.0.0 dependencies is unlikely to work, due to the changes to the API.